# Is it possible to sort questions by most viewed?

Tags: support, questions, search

I'm curious to know how to sort all of the site's questions by most viewed. Is this possible?

Is it the 'most frequent' filter?

Comment: You might be able to do this on data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this - the site is not a popularity contest, it's a place for getting questions answered.

You can however, check out the [greatest hits page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), which shows the most popular (by a metric a little more complex than just pageviews) questions over the whole site's history.